# How to get a specific node value in R

Tags: xml, r, parsing, xml-parsing

How do I access value of a particular node of an XML file using R? I am new to R and would also like to know why `xmltop[[1]]$IP` returns a null. What am I doing wrong?

```
library('XML')
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse("E:\\R Scripts\\Data\\Ipdata.xml")
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
xmltop[[1]]$IP    # return a null value
xmlValue(xmltop[[1]]$IP)    # returns NA
```

XML:

```
<Response>
<location>
 <IP>213.139.122.103</IP>
 <CountryCode>FR</CountryCode>
 <CountryName>France</CountryName>
 <RegionCode/>
 <RegionName/>
 <City/>
 <ZipCode/>
 <TimeZone>Europe/Paris</TimeZone>
 <Latitude>48.86</Latitude>
 <Longitude>2.35</Longitude>
 <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
 </location>
 <location>
 <IP>213.139.122.102</IP>
 <CountryCode>INR</CountryCode>
 <CountryName>India</CountryName>
 <RegionCode/>
 <RegionName/>
 <City/>
 <ZipCode/>
 <TimeZone>Chennai</TimeZone>
 <Latitude>48.83</Latitude>
 <Longitude>2.34</Longitude>
 <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
 </location>
</Response>
```

Comment: [`xml2`](https://github.com/hadley/xml2) is pretty nice for parsing, though you'll need your [XPath skills](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp). If you want the text contents of all `<IP>` nodes, `library(xml2) ; xml %>% read_xml() %>% xml_find_all('//IP') %>% xml_text()` where `xml` is the XML text or a path to the file.

Comment: @kumar Did my answer resolve your query? If yes, then accept and upvote.

Comment: xmltop[[1]][["IP"]] won't give you IP only. It will give you node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by this command:

```
xmltop[[1]][["IP"]]
```

Even better, you can try to use `XPATH` through `xpathApply` or `xpathSApply` command to access all `IP` tags:

```
xpathApply(xmltop, "//IP")
```

Then you can extract information from these nodes with functions such as `xmlValue`:

```
xpathApply(xmltop, "//IP", xmlValue)
```

EDIT: You need to modify your original code a litte bit (convert the objects into `XMLInternalNode`) to use the functions such as `xmlValue` as follow:

```
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse("Ipdata.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

It can be access  using`xmltop[[1]][[1]][[1]]` or  `xmlValue(xmltop[[1]][[1]])` or `xmltop[[1]][["IP"]][1]$text`. These aren't name according to the nodes.

I would recommend you to convert it to dataframe or list using this code

Data frame:

```
xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame("E:\\R Scripts\\Data\\Ipdata.xml", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

xmldataframe$IP[1]
```

List:

```
xmllist <- xmlToList("E:\\R Scripts\\Data\\Ipdata.xml")

xmllist[[1]]$IP
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful if I could I would mark both as answers.

Comment: @kumar Welcome. But you can upvote atleast my answer as mine answer was first.